# How to $_GET values from sql to be inserted in <select type> PHP

Tags: php, sql, get

I'm using xampp PHP

How to do I get values from MySQL in select type like getting value in

```
<input type="text" value="<?php $variable['valueinsql']; ?>">
```

But I want the value to be inserted in

```
<select type>
```

And I tried

```
If(isset($_GET['id'])){

<p> Banks:</p><select multiple="multiple" name="otherbanks[]" style=" width:190;" value = "<?php $list["Banks"] ?>"">
<option value="Banksone">One</option>
<option value="Bankstwo">two</option>
<option value="Bankthree">three</option>
```

I want to see it automatically highlighted.
[image: expected result]

Comment: the `option` or `options` that should be highlighted needs to have the `selected` attribute set

Comment: You want to highlight the all bank which is available in your `$list["Banks"]` ?   If yes then check answer given by me.

Comment: @Narayan Yes sir

Comment: @MonPadi Then check my answer and its correct accept it

Comment: @Narayan Error: in_array expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [in_array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) to check the value available in array or not. If available `echo 'selected';`

Try this ==>

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="otherbanks[]" style=" width:190;">
    <option <?php if (in_array('Banksone',$list["Banks"])) {echo 'selected';} ?> value="Banksone">One</option>
    <option <?php if (in_array('Bankstwo',$list["Banks"])) {echo 'selected';} ?> value="Bankstwo">two</option>
    <option <?php if (in_array('Bankthree',$list["Banks"])) {echo 'selected';} ?> value="Bankthree">three</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Error: in_array expects parameter 2 to be array, string given

Comment: can you paste value of `$list["Banks"]` here. use `print_r($list["Banks"]);`

Comment: Banksone, Bankstwo, Banksthree

Comment: its array like `Array
(
    [0] => Banksone
    [1] => Bankstwo
    [2] => Bankthree
)` like this or string

Comment: If string then make it array first by [EXPLODE](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Comment: No I used foreach when I inserted it in my database. I have a function of INSERT in my System. So whenever i'm going to choose in <select type> which of those three I wanna input, I just highlight it.

Comment: here's my code in inserting select type to explode: $banks = array();
 foreach ($_POST['otherbanks'] as $bankjoin) {
 $banks[] = (string) $bankjoin;
 }
 $banks_joined = join(', ', $banks);

Comment: Ok, then replace $list["Banks"] with $_POST['otherbanks'] in answer

Comment: why you have create a string?

Comment: can you put that in your answer? It's just saying undefined index in mine.

Comment: can you paste a line where is gives error? put in answer what ?

Comment: I just copy paste you answered except I just took only one option. And that option says Undefined index.

Comment: nothing sir undefined index. Undefined index: otherbanks

Comment: @MonPadi something wrong in your code. because above ans will definitely solve your problem

Comment: You're code works. But not in_array. I use preg_match. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

To highlight particular options the `selected` attribute should be set on each option that is applicable - as below example.

```
<select name='otherbanks[]' multiple=true>
    <option value=1 selected>one
    <option value=2>two
    <option value=3 selected>three
    <option value=4>four
    <option value=5 selected>five
</select>
```

Presumably you generate the select menu using PHP and a query to the database so to accomplish that ( highlighting ) in PHP you would need a loop to iterate through each value in `$list["Banks"]` and check the value against the value from sql. Without knowing exactly how you generate the select menu or knowing the value of `$list['Banks']` it is hard to know exactly and I may be "barking up the wrong tree" as it were.